# Для обоих детей или обоим детям?

Tags: грамматика

Что правильно:
Я купил/а новые игрушки *для обоих детей*.
или
Я купил/а новые игрушки *обоим детям*.

Comment: обе фразы корректны

Answer (score 4):

*Оба* варианта правильны. Первый акцентирует *назначение* покупки, второй - *завершённость* действия (если говорится ретроспективно, то купленное досталось обоим детям). В некоторых контекстах может возникнуть предпочтительность первого варианта, например:

> Я купил новые игрушки **для** обоих детей, но по дороге домой решил
>   подарить их старшему - близился его день рождения.